# Problem with line width in a list

Tags: lists, multicol

I have a problem with this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-designer-cv/klstlngczkld#.VecxhPmqp-E

The lists don't allow many words without breaking the line. I tried everything but can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks

ps. i'm not very experienced with latex. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by “don't allow many words"?

Comment: Thank you. I mean the width of the rows in a list is very limited. The right side of the page is empty.

Comment: The overleaf moderator said this "Hmm on lines 196 and 207, 3 columns is too narrow, thus breaking 
the list alignments. It looks like there might be some interaction between flowfram and multicol; as the \begin{multicols}{3}...\end{multicols} seems to be picking up the width of the *left* column (left of the dotted line) as its \textwidth. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out which bits to change in the template to make it work."

Comment: @egreg Do you know much about Overleaf? Seems to be a bug but I can only reproduce it on Overleaf itself at the moment.

Comment: @cfr No, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compiled the template and it looks fine (except I had to replace the image). Which lists are the concern exactly?

The lists in the `multicols` environments at the end can only take a word or two per item:

[image: skinny columns]

If you need more than this, you can use fewer columns:

```
\CVItem{Fewer columns}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Now more words will fit
    \item because fewer columns
    \item means each one is wider
    \item and each line is longer.
  \end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: fewer columns]

or no `multicols` list at all:

```
\CVItem{Single column}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
  \item Now even more words can be fitted per item within the list.
\end{compactitem}
```

[image: single column]

Showing this in context (though it is doubtless a bad idea to include so many variations on the list together in the same document):

[image: Cat's CV]

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX Template: Designer's CV
%
% Source: http://www.howtotex.com
%
% Feel free to distribute this example, but please keep the referral
% to HowToTeX.com
%
% Date: March 2012
%
% Modified by Lim Lian Tze to support multiple pages using fix provided at
% http://www.howtotex.com/templates/creating-a-designers-cv-in-latex/
% Date: November 2014
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% How to use writeLaTeX:
%
% You edit the source code here on the left, and the preview on the
% right shows you the result within a few seconds.
%
% Bookmark this page and share the URL with your co-authors. They can
% edit at the same time!
%
% You can upload figures, bibliographies, custom classes and
% styles using the files menu.
%
% If you're new to LaTeX, the wikibook is a great place to start:
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}
% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation
% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}
% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}
% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}
\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}
\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{cath}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@email.com}  \\
    \url{www.website.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak

\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} John Doe} \\
\Large\bfseries  Graphics designer \\
\normalsize\normalfont

\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem
    \item Ipsum
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem
    \item Ipsum
    \item Dolor
    \item Sit
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur
    \item Adipiscing
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Fewer columns}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Now more words will fit
    \item because fewer columns
    \item means each one is wider
    \item and each line is longer.
  \end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Single column}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
  \item Now even more words can be fitted per item within the list.
\end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If I add `showframe` to the options for `geometry` and add some more text to the columns, there does not seem to be any problem with the widths of columns in the `multicols` environment:

[image: no obvious problem]

However, if I compile this on Overleaf (replacing my cat with `example-image-a`), the output is very, very broken:

[image: broken output]

I am guessing that this is because I am compiling with an up-to-date distribution of TeX Live whereas Overleaf is not. That said, the final, frozen versions of both TeX Live 2013 and TeX Live 2014 produce the correct output on my machine. So perhaps I'm wrong about the problem.

What is clear is that this is a bug somewhere on Overleaf's side - either a buggy package or an artefact of their compilation process.

Comment: That is exactly how I wish it looked. I copied your code and the problem persists:

https://i.gyazo.com/90b47941c5318c43d276ff164ac8d6ac.png

I have no idea what to think of this. Did you use overleaf to compile?

Comment: @IlariHotti See edit. The problem is on Overleaf's side. The same code compiles fine for me with TeX Live 2015, 2014 and 2013. (I didn't test any further back.) TL 2013 and 2014 on my machine reflect the final, frozen states of the repositories for TeX Live for those years. (That is, they were completely updated before the following year's TL was released.) So Overleaf might be using an earlier snapshot from those years. Or the problem might be an entirely different one. I guess they would know this best. Perhaps refer them to this question?

Comment: @IlariHotti I've posted a comment in [the thread discussing the template on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-designer-cv/klstlngczkld#comment-2232737168). At least, I think I have. I'm not altogether clear whether anybody can see my comment, though, or even if I've managed to submit it correctly. (I have to sign up *again* here even though I'm already logged in on Overleaf. Yeesh.)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @cfr -- you're right, it was a problem with Overleaf, and adding an up-to-date flowfram.sty to the project has fixed the issue. We've now updated and republished the template to the Gallery, so it should work as expected.